# JQuery draggable stack breaks after drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm using JQuery to have draggable nameplates into slots for a website. Everything is pretty much fine, however I'm having some problems with stack. From the initial state stack works fine. All cards being dragged are always above all other elements.

The problem happens after one of the name plates get dropped in a droppable. Any draggables made draggable in script earlier will then pass under the drop nameplates. It is as if somehow the dropped nameplates get the stack property removed.

The intended function is to have the draggable always on top no matter how many times it has been dropped. I'm not sure if the CSS is interfering. I'm not too familiar with these languages.

This is setting a draggable in my code:

```
$('#rikishi_card.Gen'+i+'e').draggable( {
      cursor: 'move',
      revert: 'invalid',
      stack: '#rikishi_card'
} );
```

And then setting a dropzone:

```
$('#rikishi_slot.Gen'+i+'w').droppable( {
    accept: '#rikishi_card',
    drop: handleDrop
    } );
```

Some example code is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/10263/

Try to drag Gen1w down to new. It will successfully pass over the other cards. Then drag Gen1e over to Gen1w. It will pass under Gen1w.
Generation order is Gen1e->Gen1w->Gen2e->Gen2w

Comment: I thought I had something that if I moved all elements over to the NEW area the stack functionality was restored. But sometimes it breaks again. Then restores again by just releasing the drag then retrying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the rikishi_card from ID to class and the GenX vice versa. Seems to be working now.